Upgrade Marker to AdvancedMarkerElement
I received a notification to upgrade Marker in my generic JavaScript code. However, I don't really understand how to modify the script to use AdvancedMarkerElement instead of Marker. This code is completely generic and loads data from MySQL. The documentation is not very clear on this subject and requires some explanation to proceed with the upgrade.
    class GoogleMap {
        /**
         * @param {Object} Libraries
         * @param {Object} options
         */
        constructor(Libraries, options) {
            this.g = Libraries;
            this.OS = null;
            this.lang = null;
            this.origin = null;
            this.map = {
                id: 'gmap_map',
                options: {
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    panControl: true,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    streetViewControl: true
                },
                instance: null,
                directions: null,
                markers: [],
                infowindows: []
            };
            this.marker = null;
            this.markers = [];
            this.flags = [];
            this.goTo = null;
            this.layers = 0;
    
            this.options = {
                marker: {
                    label: false,
                    autoLabel: false
                }
            };
    
            if(typeof options === 'object') this.set(options);
            if(this.markers.length > 0) this.init(Libraries.Map, Libraries.Marker,  Libraries.LatLngBounds);
        }
    
        /**
         * @param {object} options
         */
        set(options) {
            let instance = this;
            for (var key in options) {
                if (options.hasOwnProperty(key)) instance[key] = options[key];
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Retrieve address information from marker content
         * @param content
         * @returns {{company: string, address: string, city: string, country: string}}
         */
        getAddressInfos(content) {
            var newC = {
                company: '',
                address: '',
                city: '',
                country: ''
            };
    
            content = content.split('<br />');
            newC.company = content[0];
            newC.address = content[1];
            content = content[2].split(', ');
            newC.city = content[0];
            newC.country = content[1];
    
            return newC;
        }
    
        /**
         * Change address into the direction panel
         * @param {InfoWindow} infowindow
         */
        changeDirection(infowindow) {
            let GM = this;
            GM.goTo = infowindow;
            let content = GM.getAddressInfos(infowindow.getContent());
            let pos = infowindow.getPosition();
            document.querySelector('#address .address').textContent = content.address;
            document.querySelector('#address .city').textContent = content.city;
            document.querySelector('#address .country').textContent = content.country;
            let href = (GM.OS === 'IOS' ? 'http://maps.apple.com/maps?ll=' : 'geo:') + pos.lat() + ',' + pos.lng() + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent(content.address + ',' + content.city + ',' + content.country);
            document.getElementById('openapp').setAttribute('href',href);
        }
    
        /**
         * Re center map
         * @param toBounds
         * @param offsetX
         * @param offsetY
         */
        centerMap(toBounds, offsetX, offsetY) {
            let GM = this;
            let center;
            let newCenter;
    
            if (toBounds) {
                GM.map.instance.panToBounds(GM.map.instance.getBounds());
                /*GM.map.instance.fitBounds(GM.map.instance.getBounds(),{
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: offsetX,
                    right: 0,
                    top: offsetY
                });*/
                center = GM.map.instance.getCenter();
            } else {
                center = GM.map.options.center;
                GM.map.instance.setZoom(GM.map.options.zoom);
            }
    
            let scale = Math.pow(2, GM.map.instance.getZoom());
    
            let worldCoordinateCenter = GM.map.instance.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(center);
            let pixelOffset = new GM.g.Point( (offsetX/scale) || 0,(offsetY/scale) || 0 );
    
            let worldCoordinateNewCenter = new GM.g.Point(
                worldCoordinateCenter.x - pixelOffset.x,
                worldCoordinateCenter.y + pixelOffset.y
            );
    
            newCenter = GM.map.instance.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldCoordinateNewCenter);
    
            GM.map.instance.setCenter(newCenter);
        }
    
        /**
         * Empty direction panel then check for new content to apply custom scrollbar
         */
        showDirectionPanel() {
            let directions = document.getElementById('r-directions');
            directions.classList.add('sizedirection');
        }
    
        /**
         * Show initials Markers from the map
         * @param markers
         */
        showMarkers(markers) {
            let GM = this;
            let map = GM.map.instance;
            let mm = GM.map.markers;
            for (let i = 0; i < mm.length; i++) {
                mm[i].setMap(map);
                mm[i].setOpacity(1);
                mm[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Hide initials Markers from the map
         */
        hideMarkers(markers) {
            let GM = this;
            for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
                markers[i].setOpacity(0);
                markers[i].setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * @param layer
         */
        hideLayer(layer) {
            if(layer.length > 1) {
                layer.forEach((item) => GM.hideLayer(item));
            }
            else {
                if(typeof layer.setMap === 'function')
                    layer.setMap(null);
                if(typeof layer.setOpacity === 'function')
                    layer.setOpacity(0);
                if(typeof layer.setVisible === 'function')
                    layer.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Hide everything on the map except the initials markers
         */
        clearMap() {
            let GM = this;
            let layers = GM.map.instance.data;
            for (let i = GM.layers.length; i < layers.length; i++) {
                let layer = GM.map.instance.data[i];
                GM.hideLayer(layer);
            }
            GM.layers = GM.map.instance.data;
        }
    
        /**
         * Remove direction renderer
         */
        delDirections() {
            let GM = this;
            if (GM.map.directions !== null) {
                GM.hideMarkers(GM.flags);
                GM.map.directions.set('directions',null);
                let directions = document.getElementById('r-directions');
                directions.classList.remove('sizedirection');
            }
            GM.clearMap();
            GM.showMarkers(GM.map.markers);
        }
    
        /**
         * Trace la route sur la carte
         */
        setDirection() {
            let GM = this;
            let item = GM.origin;
            let dest = document.getElementById('getadress').value;
    
            if (dest.length > 0) {
                GM.delDirections();
    
                //GM.map.instance;
                let request = {
                    origin: dest,
                    destination: GM.goTo.getPosition(),
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };
                let directionService = new GM.g.DirectionsService();
                directionService.route(request)
                    .then((result) => {
                        if (result) {
                            let leg = result.routes[0].legs[0];
                            let bounds = new GM.g.LatLngBounds();
                            bounds.extend(leg.start_location);
                            bounds.extend(leg.end_location);
    
                            let flags = [
                                {
                                    position: leg.start_location,
                                    icon: {
                                        url: "/"+GM.lang+"/gmap/?marker=grey&dotless=true",
                                        labelOrigin: {x:14, y:13}
                                    },
                                    label: 'A',
                                    content: leg.start_address
                                },
                                {
                                    position: leg.end_location,
                                    icon: {
                                        url: "/"+GM.lang+"/gmap/?marker=main&dotless=true",
                                        labelOrigin: {x:14, y:13}
                                    },
                                    label: 'B',
                                    content: GM.goTo.getContent()
                                }
                            ];
                            GM.hideMarkers(GM.map.markers);
                            flags.forEach((flagDetails,index) => {
                                flagDetails.map = GM.map.instance;
                                let flag = new GM.g.Marker(flagDetails);
                                let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                    content: flagDetails.content
                                });
                                flag.addListener('click', () => {
                                    infowindow.open({
                                        map: GM.map.instance,
                                        anchor: flag
                                    });
                                });
                                GM.flags[index] = flag;
                            });
                            if (GM.map.directions === null) {
                                GM.map.directions = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                                    preserveViewport: true,
                                    suppressMarkers: true
                                });
                            }
                            GM.map.directions.setMap(GM.map.instance);
                            GM.map.directions.setPanel(document.getElementById('r-directions'));
                            GM.map.directions.setDirections(result);
                            GM.showDirectionPanel();
    
                            let x = document.getElementById('gmap-address').getBoundingClientRect().width;
    
                            GM.map.instance.fitBounds(bounds,{
                                bottom: 0,
                                left: x,
                                right: 0,
                                top: 0
                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        alert("Could not display directions due to: " + e);
                    });
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Formulaire de recherche d'itinéraire
         */
        getDirection() {
            let GM = this;
            document.querySelector('.form-search').addEventListener('submit',(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                GM.setDirection();
            });
    
            let btn = document.querySelector('.hidepanel');
            btn.addEventListener('click',() => {
                let block = document.getElementById('gmap-address');
    
                btn.classList.toggle('open');
                block.classList.toggle('open');
            });
            let showform = document.getElementById('showform');
            showform.addEventListener('click',() => {
                if(showform.classList.contains('open')) {
                    GM.delDirections();
                    //if(self.markers.length > 1) {
                    let bounds = new GM.g.LatLngBounds();
                    GM.markers.forEach((markerDetails, index) => {
                        let point = new google.maps.LatLng(markerDetails.lat, markerDetails.lng);
                        bounds.extend(point);
                    });
                    GM.map.instance.fitBounds(bounds);
                    if(GM.map.markers.length === 1) {
                        GM.map.instance.setZoom(GM.map.options.zoom);
                    }
                    document.getElementById('getadress').value = '';
                }
                showform.classList.toggle('open');
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * @returns {{OriginContent: *, OriginAddress: *, originPosition: *}}
         */
        init() {
            let GM = this;
    
            if (GM.markers.length > 0) {
                GM.origin = {
                    OriginContent : GM.markers[0].company,
                    OriginAddress : GM.markers[0].address,
                    OriginCity : GM.markers[0].postcode + ' ' + GM.markers[0].city,
                    OriginCountry : GM.markers[0].country,
                    OriginPosition : {lat: GM.markers[0].lat, lng: GM.markers[0].lng},
                    OriginRoute: 1,
                    OriginMarker: GM.marker
                };
                GM.map.options['center'] = new google.maps.LatLng(GM.markers[0].lat,GM.markers[0].lng);
                GM.map.instance = new GM.g.Map(document.getElementById(GM.map.id),GM.map.options);
    
                let bounds = new GM.g.LatLngBounds();
                GM.markers.forEach((markerDetails,index) => {
                    let company = (markerDetails.link === '' || markerDetails.link === null) ? markerDetails.company : '<a href="'+markerDetails.link+'">'+markerDetails.company+'</a>';
    
                    let point = new google.maps.LatLng(markerDetails.lat,markerDetails.lng);
                    let markerOptions = {
                        map: GM.map.instance,
                        position: point,
                        icon: "/"+GM.lang+"/gmap/?marker=main",
                    };
    
                    if (GM.options.marker.label) {
                        if (markerDetails.label && !GM.options.marker.autoLabel) {
                            markerOptions.icon += '&dotless=true';
                            markerOptions.label = markerDetails.label;
                        }
                        else if (GM.options.marker.autoLabel && index > 0) {
                            markerOptions.icon += '&dotless=true';
                            let label = '';
                            let labelLength = 1;
                            let i = index+1;
                            if (index > 25) {
                                labelLength = Math.floor(Math.log(i) / Math.log(26));
                                for (let k = 1; k < labelLength; k++) {
                                    label += String.fromCharCode(64 + k);
                                }
                            }
                            label += String.fromCharCode(64 + i%26);
                            markerOptions.label = label;
                        }
                    }
    
                    let marker = new GM.g.Marker(markerOptions);
                    bounds.extend(point);
    
                    let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: company +'<br />'+markerDetails.address+'<br />'+markerDetails.postcode+' '+markerDetails.city+', '+markerDetails.country
                    });
    
                    GM.map.infowindows[index] = infowindow;
                    GM.map.markers[index] = marker;
                    if (index === 0) {
                        GM.goTo = infowindow;
                        infowindow.open({
                            map: GM.map.instance,
                            anchor: marker
                        });
                    }
    
                    infowindow.addListener('closeclick', () => GM.changeDirection(GM.map.infowindows[0]));
                    marker.addListener('click', () => {
                        GM.map.infowindows.forEach((iw) => iw.close());
                        infowindow.open({
                            map: GM.map.instance,
                            anchor: marker
                        });
                        GM.changeDirection(infowindow);
                    });
                });
                if(GM.map.markers.length > 1) {
                    GM.map.instance.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
    
                GM.layers = GM.map.instance.data;
    
                document.querySelectorAll('.select-marker').forEach((select) => {
                    select.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        let target = document.getElementById('#address');
                        let targetPosition = getPosition(target);
                        window.scroll({
                            left: 0,
                            top: targetPosition.y,
                            behavior: 'smooth'
                        });
                        let i = select.dataset.marker;
                        google.maps.event.trigger(GM.map.markers[i], "click");
                    });
                });
                if(GM.origin.OriginRoute && GM.goTo !== null) GM.getDirection();
                if(GM.map.options.streetViewControl) {
                    let stv = GM.map.instance.getStreetView();
                    google.maps.event.addListener(stv, 'visible_changed', () => {
                        let visible = stv.getVisible();
                        let gmapAddress = document.getElementById('gmap-address');
                        gmapAddress.style.opacity = visible ? '0' : '1';
                        gmapAddress.style.visibility = visible ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    async function initMap() {
        const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
        const { Marker } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
        const { LatLngBounds } = await google.maps.importLibrary("core");
        const { Point } = await google.maps.importLibrary("core")
        const { DirectionsService } = await google.maps.importLibrary("routes");
        const { DirectionsRenderer } = await google.maps.importLibrary("routes");
    
        let gMap = new GoogleMap({
            Map: Map,
            Marker: Marker,
            LatLngBounds: LatLngBounds,
            Point: Point,
            DirectionsService: DirectionsService,
            DirectionsRenderer: DirectionsRenderer
        }, configMap);
    }
    
    (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
        key: configMap.api_key,
        v: "weekly",
        lang: configMap.lang
        // Use the 'v' parameter to indicate the version to use (weekly, beta, alpha, etc.).
        // Add other bootstrap parameters as needed, using camel case.
    });
    
    initMap();

How do I modify my generic JavaScript code to upgrade from Marker to AdvancedMarkerElement for loading data from MySQL, as the documentation is unclear?

Can you please edit the question and put the links to the documentation you referred to? You wrote that the documentation is not very clear, but you didn't give the link to the documentation that you mention.

Stack overflow is not a free code writing service. Google has documentation about migrating to the AdvancedMarkers. Read it and come here if you have a clear and direct question.
